# Is there a way to track a user active time spent in the React web application via Google Analytics?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

Let's say an user with `user_id(1000)` and `email(user101@example.com)` logged into the reactjs based web application and browsed a few pages for `2mins` and then moved to other application tabs/windows for `30mins` and came back to the web application and browsed the app for `5more` mins on `April 1st 2021`.

I would like track/get this user's time spent report in the `Google Analytics` report saying `user101@example.com` with `user_id(1000)` has spent `7mins` on `April 1st 2021`. Is there a way to track the same via GA if possible with [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga), if it is possible how can we do it?

As of now with `react-ga` I'm tracking the `userid` property like the below:

```
ReactGA.set({userId});
```

If it is not possible via Google Analytics, is there any service provider that has this kind of feature?

Note: I have gone through existing q/a but unable to find/figure out the solution.

Comment: check these out:
https://github.com/iqbal125/react-hooks-google-analytics
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/performance-and-user-tracking-in-react-with-google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

I was able use another tracker [Riveted](https://github.com/robflaherty/riveted), which by it's definition:

> Riveted helps fix this by measuring the amount of time users are
> actively engaged (e.g., clicking, scrolling, using the keyboard) and
> then reporting the data to Google Analytics in frequent intervals.

More on it's [page](https://riveted.parsnip.io/).

While [Riveted](https://github.com/robflaherty/riveted/blob/master/riveted.js) is written with a direct global variable, we need to work around to make it available for the react project using [exports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader/).

Here is what I could achieve:

- Get the riveted.js locally as a [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robflaherty/riveted/master/riveted.js)
- Ensure to install the exports-loader via `npm install exports-loader --save`
- Import the same with the location of `revited.js` as:

  `import riveted from 'exports-loader?exports=riveted!./riveted.js';`
- After you have initialised `ReactGA.initialize(configs);`
- If you check the [source code of riveted](https://github.com/robflaherty/riveted/blob/master/riveted.js#L58), you will notice it's using the same `ga` object of `window.ga` and thus the google analytics once initialised via `ReactGA.initialize` should be enough.
- The `react-ga` provides an ability to extend `ga`. They state `ga` can be accessed via `ReactGA.ga()` [method](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#reactgaga). `This gives developers the flexibility of directly using ga.js features that have not yet been implemented in ReactGA. No validations will be done by ReactGA as it is being bypassed if this approach is used.`
- Then the `ga` allows writing a [custom plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/writing-plugins#examples)

So with all that here is what the code looks like:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import ReactGA from '../../src';
import riveted from 'exports-loader?exports=riveted!./riveted.js';

 export default class App extends PureComponent {
   constructor(props, context) {
     super(props, context);

     this.state = {
       reactGaInitialised: false,
       configs: [DEFAULT_CONFIG]
     };
   }


   initReactGA = (event) => {
     const { configs } = this.state;
     ReactGA.initialize(configs);
     // Send initial test view
     ReactGA.pageview('test-init-pageview');

     function TrackerCustomPlugin() {
         this.riveted = riveted;
     }
     TrackerCustomPlugin.prototype.init = riveted.init;

     let ga = ReactGA.ga();
     ga('provide', 'riveted', TrackerCustomPlugin);
     ga('require', 'riveted');
     ReactGA.plugin.execute('riveted', 'init', {
         reportInterval: 10,   // Default: 5
         idleTimeout: 20,      // Default: 30
         nonInteraction: true  // Default: true
     });
  };
```

Here is how the events are sent to GA from my local:

[image]

And the GA Dashboard showing `Time Spent`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still unable to figure out where the GA reports the timespent by the user over a period of time

Comment: @bravokeyl do have a check on their blog on getting this data in GA reports https://medium.com/google-analytics/how-to-track-engaged-time-in-google-analytics-84d9981920da#5884:~:text=Looking%20at%20the%20Data